# Rewrite Some code from vb.net to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have some code that i have wrote earlier in VB.NET

```
            Dim zippedLogFileName = f.FullName + ".gz"
        Try
            Using inputStream = f.OpenRead(),
                zipFileStream = File.Create(zippedLogFileName),
                compressionStream = New GZipStream(zipFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress)
                inputStream.CopyTo(compressionStream)
            End Using
        Catch ex As IOException
        End Try
```

I am trying to learn c#. But can't rewrite it to c#.
Somebody who can help me?

```
            var zippedLogFileName = f.FullName + ".gz";
        try {
            using {

            }


        catch IOException ex { }
        }
```

Comment: As a sidenote, if you have compiled (exe/dll) code in VB.NET, try opening it with ILSpy and you should see how it would be in C#

Comment: Additional sidenote - it's generally considered bad form to do nothing with an exception in a try catch block (i.e., catch (IOExpection ex) {}).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string zippedLogFileName = f.FullName + ".gz";
try{
    using(var inputStream = f.OpenRead())
    {
          var zipFileStream = File.Create(zippedLogFileName);
          var compressionStream = New GZipStream(zipFileStream,  CompressionMode.Compress);
          inputStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
     }
}
catch(IOException ex)
{
   // don't bury exceptions but rather handle them where most appropriate
}
```

Comment: It's many years later, but readers should know that this answer is incorrect. The conversion should have 3 nested 'using' blocks - VB allows specifying more than one 'using' subject at once, but C# doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to say

```
using(var inputStream = f.OpenRead()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to use **[converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)** to change code from VB to C#

Comment: Try to convert it with the convertor. :) It doesn't work.

Comment: It works, if you remove commas from end of lines

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use .NET Reflector.
It will allow you to decompile the entire compiled VB.NET project and it rewrites as C# for you :) automagically.
Of course it doesn't include comments and name of functions variables are fake, but is a very good starting point when you have to do conversions.